# MVC 3.0 RC creating new project null reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just installed ASP.NET MVC 3.0 RC and then when i am creating new MVC 3.0 project in VC 2010 I am getting a pop up dialog with the error "Object not set to an instance of an object", anyway project getting created.

Looks like visual studio couldn't find "System.Web.Mvc" assembly.
After the project was created I could add the reference manually.

But if I choose to "Create unit test project", additional unit test project is not created because of this error. In that case the MVC project gets created, but unit tests project does not.

Also I did reinstall MVC 3.0 but it is does not help.

May be some one may have how to solve this issue?

UPDATED:

After installing MVC 3.0 RTM still the same thing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error accrues only if i adding new MVC 3.0 project to the current solution inside any solution folder.

If I am creating new MVC 3.0 project not inside solution folder(in the solution root) in that case everything just fine, then i may drug and drop project whatever solution folder i want.

Anyway the problem still actual. Hopefully it will be fixed with the next MVC 3.0 release.

UPDATED

Looks like Not fixed in MVC 3.0 RTM.

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a potential bug.  I'll follow up.